# Create string formatted in C (MFC)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

How can I create formatted string in VC++ (Visual Studio 2010)?

I can create in this way:

```
CString str;
str.Format("%d bla %d", 10, 20);
```

but I want something like:

```
CString str = MACRO_OR_FUNCTION("%d bla %d", 10, 20);
```

I know how to implement it, but I preferer to use if it was implemented by MFC.

My question is: Isthis macro or function in MFC or some stand lib? If has it in MFC for example I wont implement my version. I will prefer to use it.

Comment: Why? Do you simply prefer the style better?

Comment: Yes. I need to create a lot of this formatted string in my program.

Comment: Write your `MACRO_OR_FUNCTION` that accepts the same parameters as `CString::Format` and returns a `CString`. You can use `CString::FormatV` to do the main work. There's also an example in [`CString::FormatV` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314334%28v=vs.60%29).

Comment: My question is: have this macro or function in MFC or some stand lib? If has it in MFC for example I wont implement my version. I will prefer to use it.

Answer (score 4):

You need declare a function.

```
CString fn_s_Format( LPCTSTR pctszFormat, ... )
{
    CString s ;

    va_list argList;
    va_start( argList, pctszFormat );
    s.FormatV( pctszFormat, argList );
    va_end( argList );

    return s ;
}
```